# Google Maps KML: 8-Digit Hex Code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Maps and KML.  I have my KML file rendering polygons on my map, but I would like to change the color of the fill on the pollygon and the polygon's line color.

The problem is that I am having trouble creating colors in 8-digit hex.  Every time I think I have the color right, it doesn't render like I think it would.  I can't seem to find a color editor anywhere that would allow me to generate the 8-digit hex code that I need.

Do you guys know of such an editor (Paint.NET doesnt seem to support 8-digit) or some other way to easily generate an 8-digit code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is what I use:
http://www.zonums.com/gmaps/kml_color/

([this page](http://www.zonums.com/online/color_converter/) lets you enter the code)

The hardest part is remembering the order of the pieces ([from the spec](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#color)):

```
The order of expression is aabbggrr, where aa=alpha (00 to ff); bb=blue (00 to ff); gg=green (00 to ff); rr=red (00 to ff).
```

The first two digits ("aa"/alpha in aabbggrr) represent the opacity.

Answer (score 5):

You can use 6 digit hex code in reverse for the last six characters. The first two characters represent transparency which can be set from 00 which is invisible to ff which is opaque.