# How can I set the label color for all markers in a layer in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have seen a few related questions but none answered my question completely.

This mentions Javascript: [How to override KML colors in Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610697/how-to-override-kml-colors-in-google-map)

This mentions the KML color code helper but doesn't give a solution for applying it: [Google Maps KML: 8-Digit Hex Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034702/google-maps-kml-8-digit-hex-code/13036015)

The KML reference suggests using a `<Style>` but that didn't work: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle

Is there any way to set the color (or style, generally) for all markers of a given layer, so as to distinguish it from other layers?

Comment: Why do you say `<Style>` didn't work?  How did you use it?  How are you viewing the KML?

Comment: I `Imported` the resulting KML to Google Maps and the display color was still the default. I edited the KML with Atom.

Comment: What did the "resulting KML" look like?

Comment: Added a `<Style id="foo"><BalloonStyle><color>ffd18802</color></BalloonStyle></Style>` and used `<styleUrl>#foo</styleUrl>`. So either (1) both `-normal` and `-highlight` tags are required, or `IconStyle` must be used.

Comment: Could you [edit]  your question with an example?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't perfect -- I'd rather there was an easy point-and-click way to do this in the UI -- but here goes.

Let's use a layer of markers for US National Parks as an example; taken from Wikipedia here: https://tools.wmflabs.org/kmlexport?article=List_of_national_parks_of_the_United_States

I've added these to a new map with the Import tool

[image: Screenshot of the UI showing the first several national parks; the markers are all the same blue. The first two are "Acadia" and "National Park of American Samoa".]

I think the easiest way to do this is to apply all of the desired styling to a single marker within the UI, say the first one. For simplicity I just made it orange:

[image: The same first two map icons, but now the marker for "Acadia" is orange.]

Now, export the layer to KML & open the KML file. Here's the condensed version of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>National parks</name>
    <Style id="icon-1899-0288D1-normal">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ffd18802</color>
        <!-- more attributes -->
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="icon-1899-0288D1-highlight">
       <!-- similar markup -->
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="icon-1899-0288D1">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1-normal</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1-highlight</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <!-- Two more <Style> tags for -normal and -highlight -->
    <Style id="icon-1899-F57C00-normal"></Style>
    <Style id="icon-1899-F57C00-highlight"></Style>
    <!-- Another <StyleMap> -->
    <StyleMap id="icon-1899-F57C00"></StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Acadia</name>
      <description>...</description>
      <styleUrl>#icon-1899-F57C00</styleUrl>
      <Point>...</Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>National Park of American Samoa</name>
      <description>...</description>
      <styleUrl>#icon-1899-0288D1</styleUrl>
      <Point></Point>
    </Placemark>
    <!-- More <Placemark>s for the other parks -->
  </Document>
</kml>
```

From here, we simply need to replace the reference style in the `<styleUrl>` of all of the labels with that used by Acadia. This is a simple find-and-replace-all. We can also remove the obsolete `<Style>`s and `<StyleMap>` but this is not strictly necessary. After that, save the updated KML and re-import it to Google Maps and we're done:

[image: The same parks as in the first screenshot, but now ALL the markers are orange]